# Populate 1-D Array from 2 sheets (without looping)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

**Goal**: populate 1-D array from 2 columns (in 2 different files) without looping.

[image: File 1 list]

[image: File 2 list]

The code where I'm trying to read the first list to an array fails on the line

```
MergeAccountOpportArr = NamesRng.Value
```

***Attempted code:***

```
Option Explicit

Public AccountsWB                   As Workbook
Public AccountsSht                  As Worksheet

' --- Columns Variables  ---
Public Const NamesCol          As String = "F"

' --- Public Arrays ---
Public MergeAccountOpportArr()     As String

'===================================================================

Sub MergeRangestoArray()

Dim OpportWBName As String, AccountsWBName As String, WebinarWBName As String
Dim NamesRng As Rang
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

ReDim MergeAccountOpportArr(100000) 'init size array to very large size >> will optimize later

' open Accounts file
AccountsWBName = GetFileName(ThisWorkbook.Path, "Accounts")

' set the Accounts file workbook object
Set AccountsWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=AccountsWBName, ReadOnly:=True)

' set the worksheet object
Set AccountsSht = AccountsWB.Worksheets(1)

With AccountsSht
    LastRow = FindLastRow(AccountsSht) ' get last row
    Set NamesRng = .Range(.Cells(1, NamesCol), .Cells(LastRow, NamesCol))

    MergeAccountOpportArr = NamesRng.Value ' <---- Here comes the error
End With

' rest of my code

End Sub
```

Comment: don't you need to declare the array as `Variant`?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And you also should not set the size. and let the code set the size.  The best would be to load two arrays with the values, then loop the arrays, it will be quick.  AFAIK you cannot load two separate ranges without looping.

Comment: I am just thinking out loud now.  When you assign an array from a vertical range it is always a 2D array.  So I am back to loading two arrays and looping

Comment: @ScottCraner I thought about the 2 arrays solution, I thought maybe there was a way of getting the 2 ranges directly to an array

Comment: @peakpeak what about this is not mcve?  Any less and we would be asking for more.

Comment: @ShaiRado not that I know of.  To get a 1D array from a vertical list in two separate locations you will need a loop, but as always loop arrays not ranges.  Doubt you will see any detriment to time.

Comment: This is hard enough to do with one sheet, why complicate the problem with two sheets. Figure out the first problem first before attempting to concatenate two arrays without a loop.

Comment: @ja72 because not always we have control where the data is coming from, and the format in which it comes

Comment: @ShaiRado - My point is that there are **two** questions here and [SO] works best if you ask one at a time.

Comment: @ShaiRado - FYI a Late & simple reply to your post with Scott's comment refined :-)

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you should be able to do this by hacking around with the SAFEARRAY structures in memory.  The indexing of the data area for a SAFEARRAY is determined by the product of the indexes of the individual dimensions, so if you have a two dimensional array where one dimension only has a single element, the memory addresses should be the same for a one dimensional array (row * 1 = row).

---

As proof of concept...

### YOU CAN TRY THIS AT HOME KIDS, BUT THIS IS NOT PRODUCTION GRADE CODE.

```
'In declarations section:
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias _
        "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, _
        ByVal length As Long)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias _
        "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, _
        ByVal length As Long)
#End If

Private Const VT_BY_REF = &H4000&

Private Type SafeBound
    cElements As Long
    lLbound As Long
End Type

Private Type SafeArray
    cDim As Integer
    fFeature As Integer
    cbElements As Long
    cLocks As Long
    #If VBA7 Then
        pvData As LongPtr
    #Else
        pvData As Long
    #End If
    rgsabound As SafeBound
    rgsabound2 As SafeBound
End Type
```

---

```
Public Function RangeToOneDimensionalArray(Target As Range) As Variant()
    If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Or Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        Err.Raise 5 'Invalid procedure call or argument
    End If

    Dim values() As Variant
    values = Target.Value

    If HackDimensions(values) Then
        RangeToOneDimensionalArray = values
    End If
End Function

Private Function HackDimensions(SafeArray As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim vtype As Integer
    'First 2 bytes are the VARENUM.
    CopyMemory vtype, SafeArray, 2
    Dim lp As Long
    'Get the data pointer.
    CopyMemory lp, ByVal VarPtr(SafeArray) + 8, 4
    'Make sure the VARENUM is a pointer.
    If (vtype And VT_BY_REF) <> 0 Then
        'Dereference it for the actual data address.
        CopyMemory lp, ByVal lp, 4
        Dim victim As SafeArray
        CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(victim), ByVal lp, LenB(victim)
        'Set the dimensions to 1
        victim.cDim = 1
        'Set the bound on the first dimension.
        victim.rgsabound.cElements = victim.rgsabound2.cElements
        CopyMemory ByVal lp, ByVal VarPtr(victim), LenB(victim)
        HackDimensions = True
    End If
End Function
```

Note that this has to swap the 2 dimensions (and the declarations are limited to 2D arrays). It also leaves the second dimension rgsabound "hanging", so you'll likely leak the memory for that structure (8 bytes) every time you run this.

The safer way would be to copy the contents of the memory area onto a new one dimensional array and use that instead, *OR* wrap this whole mess in a Class module and clean up after yourself when you get done.

---

Oh yeah, it works ;-)

```
Public Sub Testing()
    Dim sample() As Variant
    sample = RangeToOneDimensionalArray(Sheet1.Range("A1:A30"))

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = 1 To 30
        Debug.Print sample(idx)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that's some intense stuff, gonna need some time to learn this , thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This converts the ranges into a strings delimited by a specified character.  It then joins the two lists into an array with split()

Note:

- Delimiter will have to be a character not in your dataset
- Transpose is due to your data being in columns.  If your data is in rows you'll have to check it, maybe with something like a column count.

.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oResultArray() As String
    oResultArray = MergeRngToArray(Sheet1.Range("B3:B12"), Sheet2.Range("B2:B6"))
End Sub

Private Function MergeRngToArray(ByVal Range1 As Range, ByVal Range2 As Range, Optional Delimiter As String = ",") As String()
    Dim sRange1 As String
    Dim sRange2 As String

    sRange1 = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range1.Value), Delimiter) & Delimiter
    sRange2 = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range2.Value), Delimiter)

    MergeRngToArray = Split(sRange1 & sRange2, Delimiter)

End Function
```

Comment: Nice idea, did you get a chance to test with when the `Range` consists of 5000 cells, and the `String` is about 50,000 characters long ?

Comment: Just tossed in 11968 cells in range1, and 11969 cells in range2,  With a combined string length of 192329 characters... worked fine. According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/string-data-type) should be good to about 2 billion unicode characters

Comment: This is why an arbitrary "no loops" requirement is a bad idea.  Writing a well optimised Variant Array loop will out perform this many times over.

Answer (score 0):

## Start with the easier problem of copying cells into a 1D array

You can go from a 1D array to a range easily with the following trick:

```
Public Sub TESTING()

    Dim keyarr() As Variant

    keyarr = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

    Range("D3").Resize(5, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(keyarr)

End Sub
```

But the opposite is much harder because the `.Value` property of a range always returns a 2D array.

Except when used with the transpose function:

```
Public Sub TESTING()

    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim keyarr() As Variant

    n = Range(Range("B3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    keyarr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("B3").Resize(n, 1).Value)
    ' keyarr is a n×1 1D array

    ' Proof:
    For i = 1 To n
        Debug.Print keyarr(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

The trick is a) use the `.Transpose()` function to make a column into a single row and b) to use an array of `Variant` and not `String`. Internally the array will store strings, but the type **has to be** `Variant`.

## Now the last problem is to combine two arrays

The only solution I can think of is to combine the data into a different worksheet.

```
Public Sub TESTING()

    Dim i As Long, n1 As Long, n2 As Long
    Dim vals1() As Variant, vals2() As Variant

    ' Pull two sets of data from two columns. You could use different sheets if you wanted.
    n1 = Range(Range("B3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    vals1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("B3").Resize(n1, 1).Value)

    n2 = Range(Range("D3"), Range("D3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    vals2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("D3").Resize(n2, 1).Value)

    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(n1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vals1)
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(n1, 0).Resize(n2, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vals2)

    Dim keyarr() As Variant
    keyarr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(n1 + n2, 1).Value)


End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, I know how to use `Transpose`, I wanted to use on 2 sheets. Anyway, I ended up using @Scott Craner suggestion using 2 arrays.

Comment: See update now. Scott doesn't have an answer written up yet. Are you sure it is going to work?

Answer (score 0):

**Array approach**

```
Sub JoinColumnArrays(a, b)
'Purpose: join 2 vertical 1-based 2-dim datafield arrays based on two range columns
'Note:    returns 2-dim array with only 1 column
'Hint:    overcomes ReDim Preserve restriction to change only the last dimension!         
a = Application.Index(a, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(a) + UBound(b) & ")"), 0)
Dim i As Long, Start As Long: Start = UBound(a) - UBound(b)
For i = 1 To UBound(b)
    a(Start + i, 1) = b(i, 1)        ' fills empty a elements with b elements
Next i
End Sub
```

The above array approach returns a 1-based 2-dim array (of only 1 "column" as 2nd dimension) with changed `UBound(a)` value, i.e. the sum of the original "row" count of array `a` plus elements count of array `b`.

Note that using the `Application.Index()` function overcomes the restriction of `ReDim Preserve` which only would change an array's last dimension.

**Example Call**

```
'...
    Dim a as Variant, b as Variant
    dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
    ' Set ws1 = ...               ' << change worksheet definitions to your needs
    ' Set ws2 = ...
    a = ws1.Range("A2:B4")        ' assign column data from different sheets      
    b = ws2.Range("C2:C3")

    JoinColumnArrays a, b         ' << call procedure JoinColumnArrays

'Debug.Print "column ~>" & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(a, 0, 1)), ", ")
```